# Making Express synchronous request and sending multiple data in same one request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to make a request multiple data in one request with loop, but as far as I tried it always run Asynchronously (I guess?).
I'm using Reactjs Redux and Express.

Here's my code :

profile.jsx

```
while(i < condition.length) { // say that length = 4
   myData.forEach(item => addingData.push(item))

   // Here I'm calling my request
   this.props.addEmployee(addingData)

   // I wanted to make this 'i' increase ONLY when the request is done.
   // But I'm not sure how to do that
   i++
}
```

Express Request

```
router.post("/add-employee", (req, res) => {
    Employee.findOne({ _id: req.id }).then(user => {
       if (user) {

          const newEmp = new Employee({
              nip: req.body.nip,
              name: req.body.name
            })

          // add to employee model. Save employee
            newEmp
              .save()
              .then(user => {
                // Variable for profile
                const newProfile = {}
                newProfile.user = user._id

                // Save profile
                new Profile(newProfile).save()
                console.log("selesai save")

          res.status(200).json(user)
       } else {
          // error
       }
    })
})
```

this always returns the last data with 4 copies, which means it adding four data and its all same. How do I accomplish this, I read that this is because the request didn't run synchronously but how can I do that?

Thank you for your help!

**UPDATE**

as suggested by @Nathan Fries, I created a new router to handle the multiple requests with an array of object. But I still got the Synchronous problem (I guess?). Here's my code :

profile.jsx

```
for (i; i < this.state.file.length; i++) {
      this.state.file[i].map(item => temp.push(item))

      addData.push({
        nip: temp[0],
        name: temp[1]
      })

      temp = []
    }

// make a request
this.props.addMultipleEmployee(addData)
```

routes/api/employees.js

```
// create/add multiple karyawan
router.post(
  "/add-multiple-karyawan",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", {
    session: false
  }),
  (req, res) => {
    let errors
    let isValid
    let newEmp
    let i = 0

    // console.log(req.body) 
    // this req.body value : 
    // [{nip: "nip1", name: "name1"}, 
    //  {nip: "nip2", name: "name2"}]

    for (i; i < req.body.length; i++) {
      isValid = validationEmployee(req.body[i]).isValid
      errors = validationEmployee(req.body[i]).errors

      if (!isValid) {
        return res.status(404).json(errors)
      }

      console.log("checking for sure")
      console.log(req.body[i])
      // The value was still there


      Nip.findOne({ nip: req.body[i].nip }).then(profile => {
        if (profile) {
          return res.status(400).json({
            nip: "NIK tidak valid, karena ini adalah NIK admin. Coba lagi"
          })
        } else {

          // But when it's trying to findOne, the error message said
          // 'nip' are undefined
          Karyawan.findOne({
            nip: req.body[i].nip
          }).then(exists => {
            if (exists) {
              return res.status(400).json({
                nip: "Karyawan telah terdaftar dengan NIK yang sama."
              })
            } else {

              // adding request.body to mongoDB
              newEmp = new Karyawan({
                nip: req.body[i].nip,
                name: req.body[i].name
              })

              // add to employee model. Save employee
              newEmp
                .save()
                .then(user => {
                  // Variable for profile
                  const newProfile = {}
                  newProfile.user = user._id

                  // Save profile
                  new Profile(newProfile).save()
                  console.log("selesai save")

                  res.status(201).json(user)
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  console.log(err)
                })
            }
          })
        }
      })
    }
  }
)
```

and I got this error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nip' of undefined
[0]     at D:\Kuliah\Semester-7\ptpnx-jombang\routes\api\employees.js:198:32
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
[0] (node:22236) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
[0]     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:464:11)
[0]     at ServerResponse.header (D:\Kuliah\Semester-7\ptpnx-jombang\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
[0]     at ServerResponse.send (D:\Kuliah\Semester-7\ptpnx-jombang\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
[0]     at ServerResponse.json (D:\Kuliah\Semester-7\ptpnx-jombang\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
[0]     at D:\Kuliah\Semester-7\ptpnx-jombang\routes\api\employees.js:247:22
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
[0] (node:22236) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
[0] (node:22236) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process
with a non-zero exit code.
```

It is said that I need to make it Synchronously with Async/await or Promise? But I'm not sure how to do that. I still a novice with Async/await and Promise.

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a `/add-employees` route for handling of multiple employee additions? You could push them to an array in your jsx, then send them all at once. This avoids the `async` issue entirely.

You are also declaring `newEmp` with `const` instead of `let`. You can get the length by `req.length` and iterate through the array.

Comment: How can I count or check the length of the data on request?

Comment: Edited to answer your question

Comment: I'll mark your answer sir, now I'm trying to map an array inside a loop.

Comment: sir, I updated the question. I still got a problem with a multiple requests.